# I want a clean install of linux, are all of these partitions needed? Why is there a 999gb one?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ram

I want to make a clean install of Ubuntu. Are all of these partitions necessary? Why is there a 999GB one? I am confused as of why I have so many partitions while the videos I watched on YouTube had only 1 partition. I attempted to install Ubuntu a couple of time before and I failed, if that could be one of the causes.

[image: Installation type]

Comment: Are they all required? Can't I just leave one?

Comment: These are the partitions that are on your hard drive right now from whatever you had before on it. If you want to erase the disk anyways, you could just choose "Erase disk and install" in the step before that.

Comment: Seems like an UEFI system.  You will need an EFI(the Fat32) partition and can have the rest of drive one partition for Ubuntu.  Sized as you want.  Can use the erase disk and install option if you do not want Windows.  This will delete all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, most instructions for Ubuntu just show one big partition, but you can have multiple partitions, especially if you want to keep Windows plus run Ubuntu.

/dev/sda1 is an NTFS partition to run Windows - and you can keep it if you choose the 'install alongside' option of Ubuntu, or you can erase it and reuse it for Ubuntu if you want.

/dev/sda2 is the EFI partition, created for Windows and which Ubuntu will automatically share when you install it. Leave it alone for now unless you will completely erase the entire drive.

/dev/sda3 I can't tell what that is, but you can leave it alone for now. Please check that in Windows by right-clicking on the Windows icon then choosing Disk Management.

/dev/sda4 is NTFS also usable by Windows, your 999 GB partition which you can use for Ubuntu. That's 20X more than you'd need for Ubuntu; 50 GB is a decent amount. If you want, you can use only part of it for Ubuntu and share the rest with Windows; the Ubuntu installer will let you shrink it and take as little or as much of that as you want.

Comment: I tried to follow someone's guide and I think I messed up my partitions quite badly, i wanted to get rid of windows and I ended up having a swap partition and one root partition (with the /), and after messing around my Ubuntu has some huge lag spikes, could it be caused by my poor partitioning? Would reinstalling it and wiping the drive solve this?

Comment: Yes, it would; but for your sanity's sake, please make sure to check for data you need to preserve. Also, in the future, a CLI command you can run from a terminal window of your LiveUSB session, like _lsblk | grep -v "loop"|"tempfs"|  && df -h | grep -v "loop"|"tempfs"|_ makes a list of drive partitions in text which is easy to copy and paste into a Question and far easier to read than a screenshot or photo.

Comment: I don't need any data, so I tried to wipe everything countless times with no success. My installer either freezes from the lack of disk memory or if it doesn't,  grub gives me a fatal error. I took a photo since I was almost sure it would freeze if I did anything more. I have been trying non stop to get it to work, I will try manual partitioning from scratch, and I will see what works, while trying to follow what you explained to me earlier in the conv. Earlier I managed to delete all of the other partitions, but I still have memory issues which I think is weird.

Comment: If your LiveUSB installer misbehaves, perhaps it needs to be recreated. Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download  Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows .